# Consuming Web Services in CF 2.0

Tags: web-services, compact-framework

I made it work. However, there is a curious detail I noticed.

My Web Service is retrieving data from the database and returns a list of objects:

```
public List<RunResult> GetRunResults(string runno)
```

When called from the CF project it is shown that this web method returns RunResult[]. 
What gives?

am using CF 2.0 and the web service is also written in C#, asp.net 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web services never return a generic list.  If you need one at the consumer side just do something like this:

```
List<RunResult> list = new List<RunResult>(GetRunResults());
```

or

```
List<RunResult> list = new List<RunResult>();
list.AddRange(GetRunResults());
```

Comment: thanks, that's very useful. I must admit this is my first exposure to web services.